# Fetch last n inserted rows quickly

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql table that I only append data to. The pkey is an incrementing bigint. What is the quickest way to fetch the last n rows by inserted order (or equivalently by descending pkey)? What indices would I need to add in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres makes an index by default on primary keys. The quickest way would be to use `ORDER BY pkey DESC` and `LIMIT n`.

The following will return the last `n` records from most recent to oldest.

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
ORDER BY pkey DESC
LIMIT n
;
```

Comment: Cool, I figured that was the way to go. Just a followup, let's say that I wanted to filter based on some row. As long as those rows have indices, this should still be the faster solution right?

Comment: The filter having an index will speed up the search and removal unqualified rows. This solution would be the same but with a `WHERE` clause as a filter. Over-indexing can be detrimental so make sure you're indexing fields that are commonly used in `WHERE` or `JOIN` clauses.